# Spring Security login action does not set-cookie

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I have a spring boot project on which I have set up spring security to take care of the authentication, like is shown below (the different classes are on different files).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration(
        private val userAuthenticationService: UserAuthenticationService)
    : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(){

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        httpSecurity
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                //.antMatchers("/#/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,Constants.USERS_BASE_PATH).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                //.loginPage("/#/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/v0/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/v0/logout")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();

    }

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder?) {
        auth?.userDetailsService(userAuthenticationService)
    }

    @Bean
    fun getPasswordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder? {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

}


@Service
class UserAuthenticationService(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : UserDetailsService{
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String?): UserDetails {
        val user = userRepository.findByUsername(username!!)
        return UserAuthenticationDetails(user.username, user.password)
    }

}
```

The problem is when I perform the login action (below) it returns an HTML form to perform sign in with a 200 status code and the response does not contain the "Set-Cookie" header which would contain the cookie for following requests.

```
POST /v0/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Authorization: Basic dXNlciAxOjEyMzQ1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=user%201&password=12345
```

This is the HTML response message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Please sign in</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/signin/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/v0/login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Result must not be null!</div>        <p>
          <label for="username" class="sr-only">Username</label>
          <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
</div>
</body></html>
```

I've tried several variations of the spring security configurations but i'm definitely missing something.
What does return a "Set-Cookie" header with the correct cookie is if I try any other endpoint and just send the Authorization header with basic authentication. But for some reason this does not happen on the login endpoint.
Am I just making the login HTTP request wrong? or do I have the wrong configurations?